# CartThrob: Cannot access information in {exp:channel:entries channel="orders"} tag?

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to display information in CartThrob's "orders" channel, but cannot seem to do so. I am able access other channels' information as expected with EE's channel:entries tag pair (including other CartThrob channels), but as soon as I enter "orders" as the desired channel, everything disappears. I'm not employing any crazy conditionals or anything. It's pretty straight-forward:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders"}
<table width="80%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            #
        </td>
        <td>
            Buyer
        </td>
        <td>
            Deliver To
        </td>
        <td>
            Gift Message
        </td>
        <td>
            Options
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {title}
        </td>
        <td>
            {buyers_name}
        </td>
        <td>
            {recipients_name}
        </td>
        <td>
            {gift_message}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Print</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can output this channel's information? I assume I'm missing some sort of setting somewhere, but a search through CartThrob's documentation hasn't unveiled anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you you have your order statuses setup you will need to ad the status parameter to the channel entries tag. By default you will only see status set to open. Adding `not closed` should do the trick.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" status="not closed"}
```

will show everything status but closed but you could also specify each status you want to show.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" status="open|pending|new|processing"}
{!-- whatever status names you have setup --}
```

Comment: Justin: two words, LIFE SAVER! Thank you so much. Everything is outputting correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other params in your tag? Can you enter the entry_id of the order in question and see a specific order? (or dynamic="no" to see more?)

Comment: I have added all the parameters I can think of including dynamic="no". I'm wondering if there's some sort of permission setting that I'm missing as every other tag pair pulls data from the database including the Products channel. Is the ORDERS channel protected in some way because it stores customer data? I've not read about anything like this, but I suppose it's a possibility. I also have the feeling that I'm missing something very simple here :/

Comment: Are you setting a custom status for orders? Is there a date issue?

Comment: Jessica, this was exactly my problem. Thank you for your help!!